# How to write this update query from Mysql to Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am trying to convert this code from MYSQL to Oracle.
Can Anyone help me ? thanks!

```
 update IC_MST_CodeDateData
        left join IC_MST_Velocity
        on IC_MST_CodeDateData.whse = IC_MST_Velocity.whse and IC_MST_CodeDateData.article = IC_MST_Velocity.article
        set IC_MST_CodeDateData.velocity = IC_MST_Velocity.velocity;
```

Comment: It's really strange to include a left join in an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
update ic_mst_codedatedata c set
  c.velocity = (select v.velocity
                from ic_mst_velocity v
                where v.whse = c.whse
                  and v.article = c.article
               )
where exists (select null
              from velocity v1
              where v1.whse = c.whse
                and v1.article = c.article
             );
```

Or, using `merge`:

```
merge into ic_mst_codedatedata c
  using (select v.velocity, v.whse, v.article
         from ic_mst_velocity v
        ) x
on (x.whse = c.whse and 
    x.article = c.article
   )
when matched then update set
  c.velocity = x.velocity;
```